# Need help printing the contents of a linked list

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, dictionary, linked-list, printf

I need to make a program that reads a file, and puts all of their words in a "dictionary" as well as how often they appear and the total number of words. For example, if the file read

```
Hello, my name is Robert! My name is cool...
```

the output would be

```
hello 1
my 2
name 2
is 2
robert 1
cool 1
The total number of words is 9.
```

However, my function only prints the total number of words, and not the words themselves. Sorry if this is a trivial question, but I'm a newbie to C.

Here's the code -

http://pastebin.com/Nb30q965

Comment: I'm not sure if this is anything to do with your problem, but you have an error on line 80.  You should be using `==`, not `=`.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out! But yeah, the problem still occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is buggy in the add_to_dictionary method.

Problem #1: Line 80 should be changed to `if(stringcompare == 0)` (you are missing an =, which makes it an assignment. stringcompare will be 0 after executing instead of checking if it is 0. The result of an assignment is the value assigned and 0 is the equivalent of false in C).

Problem #2: Your loop only checks against the first item in the list. You need to remove the else.

Problem #3: Line 90 and 91 should not be in the loop. The closing brace on line 92 closes the loop.

Problem #4: In new_entry, you should `memcpy` or `strcpy` the value of stringone, instead of assigning it. Assigning a pointer makes it point to the new address. What you want to do is for the current address to have the same content as the other string. To do that, you need to go through the old memory and copy element by element into the new memory. Since you do that a lot, someone wrote a function that will do it for you (`strcpy` or `memcpy` that where mentioned before).

I didn't check the rest of the code much, so no guarantees that this list is exhaustive.

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much. I'll be sure to pay more attention next time. Sorry to take up yours and Oli's time.

Answer (score 1):

There are all sorts of problems with your code.  For instance, in your `new_entry()` function, you're assigning the address of some newly-`malloc`ed memory to `newentry->string`, but then you're immediately assigning the address of the original string to it.  This causes a memory leak (you can never get back to your `malloc`ed memory).  You're then doing `strcpy(temp->string, word)`, but they're now pointing at the same memory!  So you're copying the string into itself.

There are other issues as well (such as the incorrect use of `=` instead of `==` on line 80).

Comment: Thank you for the help, I've fixed the two problems you've pointed out. I'll admit that I'm a little slow with programming, but this is why I come for help.